# Does WebClient has HTTP connection pooling? If no, does HttpClient have it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webclient, connection-pooling, dotnet-httpclient

I want to consume a rest api from my code. Now, for this, I can use [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) or [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, HttpClient has connection pooling support, as mentioned in the documentation.

> every HttpClient instance uses its own connection pool, isolating its
>   requests from requests executed by other HttpClient instances

So, does `WebClient` has connection pooling support?

as I will be calling this api many a times, hence it do not want "creating new connections for every call" be a overhead for performance during api calls.

So which one should I be using, for better performance?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27737601/993547

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing like "connection pooling" in the HTTP world similar to "connection pooling" with databases.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thanks for the link. However, the main question still remains unanswered. Does `WebClient` has connection pooling?

Comment: It does answer your "So which one should I be using" question.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching around this to.  And found some updated information HttpClient does have connection pools.

TLDR:

```
var socketHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler()
{
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
    PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(socketHandler);
```

You can read more here: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core